# Traffic routing is failing in istio service mesh for longer URLs. Is there a limit on URL length in Istio envoy router?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

The API requests are not routing to the correct subset in Istio service mesh for longer APIs.
I tried to find the possible limits in documentation of Istio, but no luck.

I also added the debug logs in istio-proxy but I don't see any error.

Only difference between successfully routed and the failed API is that the envoy router log line for outbound traffic is missing for the failed one.

I have multiple subsets in my destination rule.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  namespace: {{ ns }}
  name: {{ dr }}
  labels:
    realm: realm
    project: proj
    Team: Name
spec:
  host: Host
  subsets:
  - name: "subset_name"
    labels:
      family: "subset_name"
  - name: "subset_name1"
    labels:
      family: "subset_name1"
```

I am trying to route an API based on a header. It is working fine for most of the APIs but for the long URLs, it's going to random subset.

Additional details:
We are using nginx as a proxy, the issue of random routing is happening from this nginx layer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a limit of 64 characters that you could be hitting in the subset, see [this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/15453) post for more information. Most likely you will need to short your subset names.

EDIT: It is not an Istio limitation, it's from k8s API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the subset names are short in our case. It seems like the APIs are not routed using virtual service but directly through nginx for long URLs